# Integer solutions to cubic equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, cubics

Part of something I'm doing at the moment results in the equation

$3k^2 + 3k + 1 = w^3$

where $k$ and $w$ are positive integers. From inspection it seems that the only integer solutions to this are the trivial pairs $(k,w) = (0,1)$, $(k,w)=(-1,1)$. This is fine, but I think I should be able to prove that these are the only possible solutions. I do not however know how to proceed - I note that the above equation can be written as

$6M + 1 = w^3$

where $M \geq 0$. Manipulating this identity, I can show that $w = 6Q +1$ but I'm not sure that helps me. Any ideas how once can proceed with this kind of proof, or is there an obvious reason why only the trivial solutions can satisfy the equation?

Comment: What is $p$? What is $w$? What is the unknown?

Comment: What do you mean by $w=(1,1)$ is a solution?

Comment: Apologies, typo corrected - k and w are both unknowns, I am simply trying to find all the pairs of integers that satisfy them. The bracketed terms are the solution sets. I've edited these to be clearer now...

Comment: And what is Q? Any integer?

Comment: Yes - any integer again. Not sure how useful it is, but put it in for clarity.

Comment: After minor transformations $k\leftarrow \frac{y-1}2$, you are looking for integer points on $$3y^2=4w^3-1$$ (in fact, you want $y$ odd).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:  and in fact one has no choice or will in the matter of $y$ odd, since $4w^2$ is even etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Does this help us much? I might be missing obvious!!

Answer (score 6):

The equation is equivalent to
$$w^3+k^3=(k+1)^3\ .$$
This has no integer solutions except when one of the terms is zero, which gives precisely the solutions you have found.

**Theorem** (Euler?).  The equation $x^3+y^3=z^3$ has no solutions in non-zero integers.

Comment: Good observation - you're right, I think that's Fermat's last theorem, but I'm curious if there's other proofs, because I have a few other forms I'd like to test for the existence of a cubic root!

Comment: It's a special case of FLT... or actually, a special case of a special case of FLT :)

Comment: The case $p=3$ was first proved by Euler, I think.